# Browser window that only shows the webpage content

Tags: linux

Would it be possible on a Linux box to show a browser window with only the content window, meaning no border around it, neither menu bars etc?

We need this for a big concert screen where a client program runs in the background. In front of that window we need to show a webpage, and it must look like the two programs are as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Browser
2. Linux window managers (especially KDE) have additional options for border and menu configurations for all/any programs separately, it's called "Window behavior":

http://userbase.kde.org/images.userbase/3/39/Config-win-behavior.png

http://www.ghacks.net/2010/02/20/window-specific-options-in-kde-4-4/

Answer (score 0):

Use Firefox and press <kbd>F11</kbd>, that should do the trick.

Edit: This will only show the browser in Full-Screen mode, and you can't see anything else. I am not sure this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try evilWM.  According to [this site](http://linuxreviews.org/software/desktops/) it's very minimalistic and good for borderless stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Run the browser on X11 WITHOUT a window manager and in fullscreen mode. Used to work with Galeon, probably can be made to work with other well preconfigured Gecko derived browsers.

Comment: Fullscreen is not an option as the window behind it must be visual.